# Spring MVC Pasar mensajes a la vista

Tags: spring

Saludos quiero en el index que se muestre el mensaje hecho en un controlador con un fondo proporcionado por Boostrap. **Al arrancar la aplicación la variable mensaje no tiene contenido** y pinta el background del boostrap.

¿ Cómo hacer para que solo se pinte si tiene datos ?

Index:

```
 <!-- Mensajes -->
         <div class="alert alert-info">${mensaje}</div>
 <!-- mensajes -->
```

Controlador :

```
ModelAndView vista = new ModelAndView() ;
vista.setViewName("index");
vista.addObject("mensaje", "Insertado Correctamente");

return vista;
```

Mi idea era : Pero da error

```
<!-- Mensajes -->
         <% if (${mensaje} != null)
             <div class="alert alert-info">${mensaje}</div>
         %>   
     <!-- mensajes -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto `<% %>` es un *scriptlet*. Dentro de este bloque estás trabajando con código Java. El código HTML va fuera.

Para acceder a un elemento añadido al `ModelAndView`, haces `request.getAttribute`.

```
<% if (request.getAttribute("mensaje") != null) { %>
         <div class="alert alert-info">${mensaje}</div>
<% } %>
```

Dicho esto, los *scriptlets* se consideran obsoletos y se recomienda encarecidamente evitarlos, sobre todo para aplicaciones nuevas. Por ejemplo, con scriptlets no se puede comprobar fácilmente que cierras el bloque del `if`, lo cual puede dar problemas en tiempo de ejecución.

Como alternativa, se recomienta usar el JSTL

```
 <c:if test="${not empty mensaje}">
      <div class="alert alert-info">${mensaje}</div>
 </c:if>
```

Esto sí que se puede analizar para verificar que tu documento es XHTML válido.

Otra alternativa es JSF, pero eso ya es un salto bastante importante